# Use a dropdown menu to display various feature layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I am trying to develop a dropdown menu that can display various feature layers, something similar to the following, except that I don't need the relocation function and when each option is selected, the previous layer will be erased and the new feature layer will be applied.
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=dataadapterfeaturelayer

This is what I have so far:

```
   JS:
       map = new Map("cpCenter", {
         basemap : "satellite",
         extent : extentInitial
         });

        map.on("layers-add-result", function() {
      query("#lplist").on("change", function(e) {
        var value = e.currentTarget.value;

        // Remove previously added layer
        if (layer) {
          map.removeLayer(layer);
          layer = null;
        }

        switch (value) {
          case "wgs84":
          case "bng":
            layer = new FeatureLayer(url);
            break;
         }

        if (layer) {
          map.addLayer(layer);
          layer.on("update-end", function() {
          map.centerAt(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(array.filter(this.graphics, function(graphic) {
              return graphic.geometry;
            })).getCenter());
          });
        }


    HTML:
       <select id="lplist">
            <option value="choose" selected="selected">(Select an option)</option>
            <option value="wgs84">XY Coordinates: WGS 84 (CoordinateLocationProvider)</option>
            <option value="bng">XY Coordinates: British National Grid (CoordinateLP)</option>
          </select>
```

Apparently this doesn't work, as no feature layer is added upon selection.
Also, I am currently having

```
    map.on("layers-add-result", function(){})
```

the basemap is able to show at this point. However, if I use

```
    map.on("load", function() {}
```

nothing will show up.